# SetInterval in a for loop , passing parameters

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

```
    var flag = true;
     function changeColor (element) {
        if(flag==true){
           document.getElementById(NAME+element).style.background="red";
           flag=false;
       }
       else if (flag==false){
           document.getElementById(NAME+element).style.background="white";
           flag = true;
     }
   }

    var temp;
    for(var i=0;i<elements_array.length;i++)
    {
      alert("VAL="+elements_array[i]);
      temp = elements_array[i];

      setInterval(function() { changeColor(temp); } ,300);
    }
```

The above code works only for the last value. I'm trying to change color a particular cell which i get from integer array(elements_array).

In the alert i get the array values correctly ,say 2,5,8. But only 8th (last) one is changing the color.

But if i hard code the values as the following all the cells change color.

```
 setInterval(function() { changeColor(2); } ,300);
 setInterval(function() { changeColor(5); } ,300);
 setInterval(function() { changeColor(8); } ,300);
```

Any ideas on why the loop is not working? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code references the same `temp` variable in all iterations of the `for` loop. That way all instances of the `setInterval` functions get passed the same reference and thus the same value (at the time of execution of the function passed to `setInterval`).

To solve this, use something like the following function to create the callback for `setInterval`

```
function createCB( val ) {
  return function(){
    changeColor( val );
  };
}
```

and change your `setInterval` call accordingly to

```
setInterval( createCB( temp ),300 );
```

The additional function call actually makes a copy of your `temp` value and thereby passes a different value to each call of `changeColor`.

Comment: It works with Internet explorer but not on chrome. On Chrome it starts to change color once and it stops. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @m4n07 I don't know, if this is your desired behaviour, but the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuguZ/), works fine with my chrome (19). The problem may be the global `flag` variable. Possibly there should be one `flag` per element.